Visual Studio Code Remote SSH localizes ssh incorrectly
I would like to program a Beagle Bone Black over remote SSH like in Eclipse. By executing the ssh connection there are always errors.
I am trying to reach the connection via remote SHH on a computer with a Beagle Bone Black. Unfortunately Visual Code uses the following path:
[16:28:09.660]Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe -V" [16:28:09.665] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe ENOENTt
with the command:
where.exe ssh
I get the path
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
how can I change the path for that?

To achieve what you need, you should edit the settings.json to change the path to the one you want. You can reach that file by clicking on "file" > "Preferences" > "Settings". Then in the research bar, write "ssh", you should have the option to edit "settings.json". In the file you can then add or edit the line as follows:
"remote.SSH.path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"

